# Recover cleared passwords from your Google account

Tags: google-account, google-chrome, account-recovery

Yesterday I cleared all my personal info from my laptop before sending it off to the menders for them to install a new keyboard and look at an issue with over-heating.

Today I logged into my desktop to find not only did I clear all my personal details from there, but from here too.

I have checked my password list at passwords.google.com and there are no longer any passwords saved.

Is it possible to recover these? I have searched but all i can find are instructions on how to view the currently saved one.

Answer (score 2):

It should not be possible to recover the lost passwords.

Somehow Google thinks you intended to delete those saved passwords from your account, so now they are gone.

You will need to use the password recovery process for each service that you lost the password for.

Comment: Why dont the users exist anymore/?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post, but see my solution which works under certain conditions here: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/188568168?hl=en&msgid=191560279